# Replace many values in a string based on search/replace pairs

Tags: javascript

How can replace values as array by replace in javascript.

I want done replace numbers (for example) together. how is it?

`1` -replace whit-> `11`
`2` -replace whit-> `22`

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ygxfy/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var array = {"1":"11", "2":"22"}
    var str="13332";
    document.write(str.replace(array));
</script>​
```

Comment: But there is no array...

Comment: That is not an array, that is a variable named "array" that is referencing an object. Note also that it is just about never appropriate to use `document.write()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create a pattern, using a RegEx, and then pass it to the `.replace` method.

```
var array = {"1":"11", "2":"22"}; // <-- Not an array btw.
// Output. Example: "1133322"
document.write( special_replace("13332", array) );

function special_replace(string_input, obj_replace_dictionary) {
    // Construct a RegEx from the dictionary
    var pattern = [];
    for (var name in obj_replace_dictionary) {
        if (obj_replace_dictionary.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            // Escape characters
            pattern.push(name.replace(/([[^$.|?*+(){}\\])/g, '\\$1'));
        }
    }

    // Concatenate keys, and create a Regular expression:
    pattern = new RegExp( pattern.join('|'), 'g' );

    // Call String.replace with a regex, and function argument.
    return string_input.replace(pattern, function(match) {
        return obj_replace_dictionary[match];
    });
}
```

Comment: Very nice. It might be even nicer if you (or the OP :) wrapped this up as a reusable function.

Comment: @Phrogz I've turned the thing in a re-usable function. Also omitted `Object.keys`, since I had to loop through the keys anyway.

Comment: Very nice. Any reason you used `/(...)/,'$1'` instead of `/.../,'$&'`?

Comment: @Phrogz Because I've written the RegEx escaping method a while back, without considering `$&`. `$&` does also work.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/uHUs9/

You can pass a function into the [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method

```
RegExp.escape = function(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}

String.prototype.mapReplace = function (replacements) {
    var regex = [];

    for (var prop in replacements) {
        regex.push(RegExp.escape(prop));
    }

    regex = new RegExp( regex.join('|'), "g" );

    return this.replace(regex, function(match){
      return map[match];
    });
}


var map = {"1":"11", "2":"22"};    
var str="13332";

document.write(str.mapReplace(map));​
```

Comment: This is a good js regex primer. I Might try to use the esajilla for this use case as a simpler implementation.

Comment: Small mistake in function String.prototype.mapReplace : map is not defined. replacements should be used instead of map (or renamed to map).

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "13332",
    map = {"1":"11", "2":"22"};

str.split("").map( function(num ){
    return map.hasOwnProperty(num) ? map[num] : num;
}).join("");

//"1133322"
```

Comment: @JuanMendes `"23333"` is the result using that map, is that not the expected result? Also, using that map with `"123"` results in `"233"`, so please try the code before shaming it ;P

Comment: How to make this work for variable length to-be-replaced patterns?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rep = {"1":"11", "2":"22"}
    var str="13332";

    for (key in rep) {
        str = str.split(key).join(rep[key]);
    }

    document.write(str);
</script>​
```

Comment: @spacevillain Did you try this?

Comment: I did and I don't get what is wrong with it. 1 gets replaced by 11, and 2 by 22, resulting in 1133322

Comment: For non-repeated keys, and non-modified prototypes, this method is sufficient. However, when keys may interfere with each other, a problem arises. Example: `1-2, 2-3` on `123` becomes `333` instead of `233` (the 1 is replaced with 2, then with 3).

Comment: @RobW I think the argument about modified prototype is a different one. Not everyone wants to use `hasOwnProperty` in their `for in` loops if they've made a decision not to use libs that modify `Object.prototype`. Discussions about that should not spill into every example that uses `for in`

Comment: @JuanMendes I only mentioned the prototype for completeness. The biggest issue is that the whole string is used for the replacement, which may lead to unexpected results (as shown in the simple example in my comment).

Answer (score 0):

What about using `reduce` function ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var array = {"1":"11", "2":"22"};
  var str = "13332";

  str = Object.keys(array).reduce(function(result, key) {
    return result.replace(new RegExp(key, 'g'), array[key]);
  }, str);

  document.write(str);
</script>
```